# Docker builds on TeamCity cloud agent

Tags: azure, docker, teamcity, azure-container-instances

I’ve never worked with cloud profiles on TeamCity and have a question regarding the Docker build runner...

I’ve got a TC agent pool running containers an Azure Container Instances. I’d like to use the agents in this pool to run Docker build and push commands with the TC Docker runner but this obviously requires Docker to be installed on the agent.

How have people got round this? Docker in Docker?

Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand you clearly. If you mean run the Docker command without installing Docker?

Comment: I want to switch to Docker build agents running on Azure Container Instances which I’ve configured and works great for Node, .NET Core etc. builds. I also build and push Docker images for my containerised apps but I can’t build these using the TC Docker build agents and the Docker build runner because the TC image doesn’t have Docker installed and therefore the agent requirements are not met.

Comment: So my question is, do I need Docker in Docker on the TC Docker image to use the Docker build runner with cloud profiles or is there another way?

Comment: I have no experience with TC. But if you want to run Docker in Azure Container Instance, it seems impossible. You can try to run Docker in Docker on the Azure VM or AKS with [a specific size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Charles. Aware that I can just use an Azure VM with Docker installed but I want to move away from VM build agents. Interesting comment about not being able to use Docker in Docker on ACI but suggesting AKS instead. Can you expand on that? Why would I not be able to use it in ACI but able to in AKS?

Comment: The Docker in Docker needs the Nest Virtualization and it relies on a specific size on Azure. You cannot set the size for ACI but you can do that for AKS.